# Microsoft Band tiles

Tags: tiles, microsoft-band

When I create a new tile (`TileManager.AddTileAsync`) that tile does not appear in the Microsoft Health app on the phone.

Additionally, if I loop through all the tiles in the tiles collection (using `TileManager.GetTilesAsync()` that new tile is the only one that is returned -- the default tiles provided with the band are not returned. Am I correct in assuming that it is up to the app I create to provide a storage mechanism and tile management for these tiles? Where to store it? In isolated storage on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the latest version of the Microsoft Health application, all custom Tiles added to the Band *should* be listed as a "Third Party Tile" on the Manage Tiles page of the application. This ensures that Tiles can be removed from a Band even when the application that added the Tile has been uninstalled.  When called by an application, IBandTileManager.GetTilesAsync() will enumerate only Tiles that have previously been added **by that application**.  That is, applications will only see its own Tiles and no others, nor will it see the built-in Tiles.

If the application uses a fixed number of custom Tiles I would recommend that each custom Tile use a fixed (i.e. static) Tile ID (as opposed to generating a unique GUID when adding the Tile to the Band).  This ensures that application can identify each of its Tiles without using any other storage mechanism and regardless of the phone with which the Band happens to be paired.

If the application generates a dynamic number of Tiles, then obviously it must store a map between a particular Tile (ID) and the entity represented by that Tile.

Comment: i have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660137/adding-tile-to-ms-band-warning-ios/30040369#30040369    are you saying that before any 3rd party app can make a tile on the band the user need to add it in microsoft health? I tried looking in there but I couldn't find anything about 3rd party tiles.

Comment: No, any given application can add one (or more) Tiles to the Band (with user-consent).  However, only the application which added a given Tile can update or remove that Tile.  The one exception is that all Tiles added to the Band (by any application) will be shown in the Microsoft Health application (listed under 3rd Party Tiles).  (The reason for that is to allow the application to be removed even if the application which added the Tile has been uninstalled.)